# Create time-series data in SPARQL query

Tags: time-series, sparql

I try to create a SPARQL query that returns the number of items at a specific point in time. To create a time series I use the `VALUES` keyword:

```
VALUES ?date {
        "1960-01-01"^^xsd:date
        "1970-01-01"^^xsd:date
        "1980-01-01"^^xsd:date
        "1990-01-01"^^xsd:date
        "2000-01-01"^^xsd:date
        "2010-01-01"^^xsd:date
        "2020-01-01"^^xsd:date
    }
```

In the end, I will `GROUP BY ?date` to get the solution. But this is a bit cumbersome especially if the time series gets longer or needs more resolution. Is there a way to create bindings for `?date` more elegantly (something similar to python `range()`)?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the SPARQL functions around date here:
https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-date-time

You can use the regular operators to do date arithmetic in most SPARQL engines, within filters, such as <= (less than or equal to). So this enables you to specify a range.

For example, in Amazon Neptune, xsd:dateTime values are stored as UTC, which makes direct comparisons easy.

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. To clarify my question. I'm looking for a way to create the bindings for `?date` programmatically by stating a start and end date and probably an incrementation interval (and not as in the question shown with the `VALUES` keyword). Because I will have dozens of entries for the `?date`. The final date comparison is not the problem.

Comment: Your best bet is to use a library like rdflib in python or rdf4j in java to programatically build the filter.